# Azure Self Hosted Agents not picking up on installed dependencies

Tags: azure, azure-devops

When trying to install tools like python, AZ CLI, updating tool versions, or etc, despite RDP'ing into the server and installing via Powershell, the pipeline still declares them either not installed, or still reflects the old version, even when confirming install/version in shell in RDP. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you restart the agent service after updating the dependencies?

Comment: @DanielMann I don't know that I did. I suppose I didn't think I had to because you usually dont have to restart things when installing in shell. Does the agent only pick up installed dependencies at startup?

Comment: Capability discovery occurs on agent start for system-wide capabilities. You can also use tool installers within the pipeline to provide on-demand installation and configuration of appropriate toolsets. i.e. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/use-python-version?view=azure-devops

Comment: @DanielMann So in otherwords, after installing any dependencies, the agent needs to be restarted to pick up new tool installations? We were installing dependencies in pipeline before, but we are using a self hosted agent and trying to install the dependencies permanently to reduce runtime of the pipeline and reduce complexity/ensure consistency between pipelines. Apologies for the long time on response.